# Django - Celery Creating a PeriodicTasK from my model

Tags: django, celery, periodic-task

I have this model

```
class Discoveries (models.Model):
  creation_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  last_run        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  created_by      = models.CharField(default="Admin", blank=False, max_length=250)
  name            = models.CharField(blank=False, default="Default Network Discovery", max_length=250)
  target          = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=250)
  ports           = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
  options         = models.CharField(default="-T4 -sV -A  -PS", max_length=350)
```

I have this task

```
@app.task

def run_discovery(data):


    n = discovery.discovery()
    run = {'target': data['target'], 'options':data['options']}

    b = n.run_discovery(run)
```

My problem, the "data" to run task is a Discovery model instance, How to Associate a Discoveries Model to a PeriodicTask ?
I my frontend I have a Form to create Task and select same params to create the PeriodkTask, then when de user Save a new Disvory I wanna create a new Periodic Task Based on this Parameter.

Comment: Just a note: You should never pass object to celery task. Instead pass just `discovery.id` and fetch it from database.

Comment: @satevg thanks for your time, but I forget to say,  this tasks will run on remote workers than they can not access the database !!